# How to setup coremltools convert model output shape using yolo.h5

Tags: swift, keras, yolo, coreml, coremltools

I try to convert `h5` to iOS `mlModel`.

I follow Quick Start to get `h5` file by this link.

https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3

Then, I use `coremltools` to convert `h5` to `mlModel`

this is my code

```
mlModel = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('./yoloDone.h5',
                                            input_names='image',
                                            image_input_names='image',
                                            input_name_shape_dict={'image': [None, 416, 416, 3]})
```

But I find some error in output shape.

This is correct output.

[image]

This is my output, the type is not same.

[image]

The correct model, `output1` is 255x13x13.

But my model, `output1` is 1x1x255x13x13.

What should I do to edit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1x1x255x13x13 is the same thing as 255x13x13 except that you have 5 dimensions instead of 3.

If you want the mlmodel to output 255x13x13, you'll have to fill in the output shape in the `spec.description.output` using coremltools.

Comment: https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/issues/63
Thanks for your answering. The link is about detail how to solve problem.